# Sum of 2 fetched columns in other column in Big query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, calculated-columns

```
select x,
count(case when i='abc' then 1 else null end) as ele1,
count(case when i='def' then 1 else null end) as ele2,
sum(ele1+ele2) as sum1 from (INNER QUERY)
```

When i am using sum(ele1+ele2), it is throwing error that ele1 not found. How to fetch sum1 in the same query without using any other outer query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use alias as column name in select

```
select x,
count(case when i='abc' then 1 else null end) as ele1,
count(case when i='def' then 1 else null end) as ele2,
sum(  ( case when i='abc' then 1 else null end  ) +  
    ( case when i='def' then 1 else null end ) ) as sum1 
from (INNER QUERY)
```

Comment: I though of the same but is there no other method because in this case again we have to apply the condition which will increase the querying time

Comment: it can also be done as count(case when i='abc' || i='def' then 1 else null end) as sum1...but is there any other method to do it?

Comment: My answer is for solve the throwing error and for this the answer is right .. for a better query there are several different solution but this seems another question ..... in term of execution time the Or solution you provide ,, the in solution or the two case slution are very silmilar .. anyway

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use alias as a column name, but if your concern is in verboseness - in your particular case you can write something like below, which is easy readable and skinny enough (for BigQuery Legacy SQL)

```
SELECT 
  SUM( i ='abc' ) AS ele1,
  SUM( i = 'def' ) AS ele2,
  SUM( i IN ('abc', 'def') ) AS sum1 
FROM (INNER QUERY)
```